# Need help to fix code to take value from textbox into a variable in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm quite new to coding and I was wondering how i could take what someone types in a textfield and use it later on.

Code: Textbox is called `classIn` and is restricted to only take Numbers between 1 and 4.

```
var class:Number = classInn.text;

var key:uint = 0;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, nextRoom);

function nextRoom(evt:Event)
{
    key = evt.keyCode();

    if(key == 70)
    {
        if(class == 1){ gotoAndStop("Task1");}
        if(class == 2){ gotoAndStop("Task2");}
        if(class == 3){ gotoAndStop("Task3");}
        if(class == 4){ gotoAndStop("Task4");}
    }   
}
```

Comment: You should not use **class** as a variable name as it is a reserved word. Also, you should describe the problem you've encountered, not the desired result only, because StackOverflow is not a free code delivery service, it is "point me where I am wrong" service.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
var class:Number = classInn.text;
```

That `.text` is a [**datatype**](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/datatype.htm) of `String` and here you're trying to set a string of *text* as the *numerical* value of a `Number` datatype. The two things are not compatible.

Solution: Use **casting** to convert the digits within `classInn` text into a number.

```
var class:Number = Number(classInn.text); //cast into Number datatype
```